# How do you use batch IF EXIST to test directories?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, scripting, directory

The batch here inserts file correctly but provides odd output for the IF EXIST. I have verified the issue as being with the statement by the echos before and after it, but the IF EXIST is pinging as true if the copy is going off. The error I get is the console text of "The system can not find the drive specified."

Code is below.

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO This batch file will place the background and user icons for Windows 7 install.

SET directoryName=C:\Users\yourname\Desktop\BatchTestingFolder\ImageInsertReal\testfolder

ECHO %directoryName%
PAUSE

IF EXIST guest.bmp ( 
::If image exists
ECHO 1
::1--
IF EXIST %directoryName% ( 
    ::If directory exists
    ::insert all below images
::2--
    ECHO 2
    COPY /-Y guest.bmp %directoryName% ) ELSE (
    ::Else echo directory doesnt exist
::2--
    ECHO The folder %directoryName% does not exist. 
goto ENDER ) ) ELSE (   
::Else echo image doesn't exist
::1--
ECHO Images do not exist in current batch file directory. 
goto ENDER )

::Exit insertion
:ENDER
PAUSE
```

Comment: Use a backslash at the end when check if a directory exists. You also should not use double colons as a comment inside a parentheses code block.  You will get some undesirable output from that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly advise you use a syntax of coding that is readable.

- Proper indentation helps with readability of parentheses code blocks.
- Using a double colon as a comment inside a parentheses code block can cause undesirable code output.
- You can use a backslash to make sure you are testing for the existence of a directory.
- Use quotes around your file names and file paths to protect spaces and special characters.

This may fix your problems.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO This batch file will place the background and user icons for Windows 7 install.

SET "directoryName=C:\Users\yourname\Desktop\BatchTestingFolder\ImageInsertReal\testfolder"

ECHO %directoryName%
PAUSE

IF EXIST guest.bmp ( 
    REM If image exists
    ECHO 1
    REM 1--
    IF EXIST "%directoryName%\" (
        REM If directory exists
        REM insert all below images
        REM 2--
        ECHO 2
        COPY /-Y guest.bmp "%directoryName%\"
    ) ELSE (
        REM Else echo directory doesnt exist
        REM 2--
        ECHO The folder %directoryName% does not exist. 
        goto ENDER
    )
) ELSE (
    REM Else echo image doesn't exist
    REM 1--
    ECHO Images do not exist in current batch file directory. 
    goto ENDER
)

::Exit insertion
:ENDER
PAUSE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help. I suppose the backslash makes it look for a folder instead of a file? Either way, thanks for formatting help. It looked quite good on my screen, but copy pasting made it quite ugly sadly. Spent a bit cleaning up to be somewhat readable. Works perfectly for anyone else wondering.

Comment: @Zaozin, I have no problems copying the code and pasting it into notepad.  Looks exactly the same.